# About 3D effect in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, 3d

I'm developing WPF SW, and I see the 3D effect is very slow if we did it in XAML file, I want to know if there is a book which introduce how to do 3D effect in WPF? Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two WPF books on 3D that I have - one is Charles Petzolds "3D Programming for Windows", which provides a great walk through the topic and is quite practical. The second is Practical WPF Graphics Programming by Jack Xu, which does go a little deeper, but seems to follow a pattern of a few paragraphs of text, followed by 3 pages of code/XAML, then a picture or two.

I don't recall either covering performance in depth, though general tips are given. Out of interest, how large is your mesh?

In general 3D for WPF is great for augmenting a 2D application, but it isn't really designed for fully-3D, high performance graphics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading [Practical WPF Graphics Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0979372518) by by Jack Xu at the moment. It has 6 (of 14) chapters about 3D. From simple transfomations to custom 3D shapes. It also has chapters about physics, games and charting.

I can recommend that book, if you would like to know more about 3D in WPF.